# How to create a numpy array from itertools.combinations without looping

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Is there a way to get this result without a loop? I've made a couple attempts at fancy indexing with `W[range(W.shape[0]),`... but have been so far unsuccessful.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
n = 4
ct = 2
one_index_tuples = list(itertools.combinations(range(n), r=ct))
W = np.zeros((len(one_index_tuples), n), dtype='int')
for row_index, col_index in enumerate(one_index_tuples):
    W[row_index, col_index] = 1
print(W)
```

Result:

```
[[1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indexing a numpy array with a list of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491230/indexing-a-numpy-array-with-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fancy indexing ([advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)) as follows:

```
# reshape the row index to 2d since your column index is also 2d so that the row index and 
# column index will broadcast properly
W[np.arange(len(one_index_tuples))[:, None], one_index_tuples] = 1

W
#array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
#       [1, 0, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0, 1],
#       [0, 1, 1, 0],
#       [0, 1, 0, 1],
#       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[ 1 if i in x else 0 for i in range(n) ] for x in itertools.combinations( range(n), ct )]
```

Comment: this is still looping tho ;)